# Why is Brooklyn Nine-Nine not on Netflix despite the announcement?

Tags: distribution, netflix, brooklyn-nine-nine

I've read before that Season 6 of *Brooklyn Nine-Nine* should be released on Netflix in March 2020 in multiple countries, including the Czech Republic:

- https://nextalerts.com/brooklyn-nine-nine-season-6-release-date-on-netflix-and-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-series-28/
- https://www.whats-on-netflix.com/news/brooklyn-nine-nine-season-6-coming-to-netflix-march-2020/
- https://newsdio.com/brooklyn-nine-nine-season-6-will-arrive-on-netflix-in-march-2020/37871/

But I'm in the Czech Republic and I don't see it there, so: **why is it not on Netflix despite the announcement?**

Was the contract canceled?

Answer (score 2):

## It’s on Netflix only in Japan, Canada or the UK.

According to [this website](https://www.vpnmentor.com/blog/watch-season-5-brooklyn-nine-nine-anywhere/), it seems like it’s more of that silly licensing nonsense in play again. So no Brooklyn Nine-Nine in the  Czech Republic it seems.

> **Brooklyn Nine-Nine is on Netflix!** Noice, right?
>
> Well, it is if you’re based in **Japan, Canada, or the UK**. For viewers outside of these countries, **Netflix geoblocks Brooklyn Nine-Nine** to abide by licensing laws.

Comment: hm, but the articles in the question specifically mentions the Czech Republic. Did something change then?